# Replace string values with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, oracle10g

I have the following string containing column names:

```
string colsToSelect;
```

This string contains column names (e.g: col1+col2+col3+col4+col5 or col1+col3) and in those columns there are numerical values.

I am using this to get the total of all these columns from database.

```
SELECT " + colsToSelect + " AS totalVolume " + "FROM myTable
```

However I need to add nvl(col1,0) to each of the columns as those columns may contain null.

I have achived it like this:

```
    colsToSelect = colsToSelect.Replace("+", "+nvl(");
    colsToSelect = colsToSelect.Replace("+", ",0)+");
    colsToSelect = "nvl(" + colsToSelect;
    colsToSelect = colsToSelect + ",0)";
```

This gives me `nvl(col1, 0) + nvl(col2, 0)` etc.. but I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving this, possibly with LINQ or with sql?

Comment: My solution isn't any better:  `colsToSelect.Split("+");`  Then `.ForEach()` to pre-pend "nvl(" and append ",0)" and join them back together.  No better than what you have.  (`colsToSelect.Split("+").ForEach(c=> return "+nvl(" + c + ",0)").ToString();`

Comment: Why is your input coming in as a single string and not a list of strings, or some other data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.Split`, then `string.Join` again:

```
colsToSelect = string.Join("+", 
                    colsToSelect.Split('+')
                                .Select(x => string.Format("nvl({0}, 0)", x)));
```